# Magento 1 + Turpentine versus Magento 2 + Varnish

Tags: magento-2.1, varnish

I am using `(Magento 1 + Nexcess Turpentine)` combination for a long time with very good results. Now I am playing with `Magento 2.2.0` and it has its own internal mechanism for doing the job with `Varnish`, but it is out of the box.

Comparing with the one in Magento 2, Nexcess Turpentine extension is a great tool for Magento 1, with lots of features and abilities to control the cache for almost everything you need. Is anyone who used `Varnish` with Magento 2 and can provide some feedback comparing to (Magento 1 + Turpentine)?

Answer (score 1):

## Magento 1 + Turpentine

Turpentine is [not really a full page cache solution](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/turpentine-is-not-full-page-cache) because it requires first request for each visitor to suffer complete **uncached** experience.

Read: every time a user lands to your page, they will hit uncached page. Sounds great? I don't think so. Landing experience is most crucial for customer conversions.

## Magento 2

Magento 2 Varnish support *is* complete full page cache solution, because it doesn't suffer from M1 + Turpentine limitation. It can serve full page cache hit for every landing visitor.

That said, Magento 2 is *much* slower compared to Magento 1 in terms of PHP execution times. So a cache warmer plugin is a must for use with Magento 2.

Comment: I agree you related to the first bite using Turpentine. On the other hand, Magento 2 without Varnish is very slow, activating it is a necessity. Did you get any situations when visitors got wrong private content?

Comment: Yes. M2 is unbearably slow absent caching. What you ask - never happened.

Comment: lol running turpentine varnish cache from day one - it works just perfect - page cached only once. there are no any limitations.